# Goutte скачивание файла по ссылке

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, curl, codeception

Здравствуйте. Задача:
на странице есть ссылка, по нажатию на которую отдается файл.
Как я пробовал:

```
$crawler = $client->getClient()->get($link, [
    'save_to' => storage_path(),
]);
```

Ошибка 403. Пробовал добавлять header с referer - не помогло.

```
$crawler = $client->click($link);
```

Не выдает ошибок, но ничего не скачивает, что вполне логично, т.к. при нажатии выскакивает диалог с выбором пути.

Я в поисках решения слегка иссяк, так что выручайте...
Заранее спасибо.